# Structure size and memory layout depending on #pragma pack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, memory-alignment, pack

Consider the following program compiled in VC++ 2010:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)    // 1, 2, 4, 8
struct str_test
{
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned short s;
    unsigned char b[4];
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
    str_test str;
    str.n = 0x01020304;
    str.s = 0xa1a2;
    str.b[0] = 0xf0;
    str.b[1] = 0xf1;
    str.b[2] = 0xf2;
    str.b[3] = 0xf3;

    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)&str;
    std::cout << sizeof(str_test) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I set breakpoint on `return 0;` line and look memory window in the debugger, starting from address `p`. I get the following results (`sizeof` and memory layout, depending on `pack`):

```
// 1 - 10    (pack, sizeof)
// 04 03 02 01 a2 a1 f0 f1 f2 f3

// 2 - 10
// 04 03 02 01 a2 a1 f0 f1 f2 f3

// 4 - 12
// 04 03 02 01 a2 a1 f0 f1 f2 f3

// 8 - 12
// 04 03 02 01 a2 a1 f0 f1 f2 f3
```

Two questions:

1. Why `sizeof(str_test)` is 12 for pack 8?
2. Why memory layout is the same and doesn't depend on the pack value?

Comment: Your "output" isn't consistent. You have a sizeof==12 and a dump of 10 bytes?

Comment: @harper - bytes after `f3` are `cc` for all pack values (uninitialized memory in Debug configuration).

Comment: I read `// 8 - 12` that the size is 12 bytes. I just wondered why you omitted the trailing `CC`s. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why sizeof(str_test) is 12 for pack 8?

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx):

> The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a
>   multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is
>   smaller.

In your case the largest member is 4bytes which is smaller than 8, so 4bytes will be used for alignement.

> Why memory layout is the same and doesn't depend on the pack value?

The compiler isn't permited to reorder struct members, but can pad the members. In case of pack 8 it does the following;

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)    // largest element is 4bytes so it will be used instead of 8
struct str_test
{
    unsigned int n; // 4 bytes
    unsigned short s; // 2 bytes        
    unsigned char b[4]; // 4 bytes
    //2 bytes padding here;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

And hence sizeof(str_test) will be 12.

Well, it seems the compiler (MSVC2010) change padding location based on the type, in the case of  `unsigned char b[4];` it placed two bytes padding at the end of the structure. In your case the 2 bytes `cc cc` happens to be after the character array.

```
#pragma pack(push, 8)    // largest element is 4bytes so it will be used instead of 8
struct str_test
{
    unsigned int n; // 4 bytes
    unsigned short s; // 2 bytes 
    //2 bytes padding here;       
    int;  // 4 bytes

};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

What I did is change the last member from `char[4]` to `int`, and can be verified by subtracting the addresses of the last and first member in both cases 6 and 8 respectively.

Memory dump in the case of last member `int` as follows

```
04 03 02 01 a2 a1 cc cc f0 f1 f2 f3
```

Memory dump in the case of last member `unsigned char[4]` as follows

```
04 03 02 01 a2 a1 f0 f1 f2 f3 cc cc
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the `whichever is smaller` point. But it is still not clear, why I don't see 2 bytes padding in the memory window.

Comment: Thanks, your note `Memory dump in the case of last member int` explains everything, #2 is answered.